# Generic left side interface parameter

Tags: c#

I have a generic type parameter in my classes. Why can I do this:

```
BaseFoo<InterfaceImplementation> foo = new ChildFoo<InterfaceImplementation>();
```

But not this? Shouldn't the compiler be able to figure out that `AnInterface` is an implementation of `InterfaceImplementation`?

```
BaseFoo<AnInterface> foo = new ChildFoo<InterfaceImplementation>();
```

I was hoping to be able to do something like this:

```
BaseFoo<AnInterface> foo = new ChildFoo<InterfaceImplementation>();
BaseFoo<AnInterface> bar = new ChildFoo<AnotherInterfaceImplementation>();
```

Where both implementations have a common interface.

Comment: Convert `BaseFoo` to an interface and use [Co- and Contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).

Comment: Something along the line of 'An orange is a fruit, but you cannot treat a basket of oranges as a basket of fruits, since then you can add a banana to the basket', but somehow I always get the metaphor wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact, that

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
```

doesn't mean, that

```
class C<B> : C<A> {}
```

You need variance, but in C# it works only with interfaces and delegates.
You may declare variant interface and choose from co- and contravariance:

```
IBaseFoo<out T> {} // this is covariant interface
IBaseFoo<in T> {} // this is contravariant interface
```

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).